# Terminal can't run apktool

Tags: java, android, bash, apk

I am using macOSX, and trying to extract all the files in a APK file, I've extracted it with zip and unzip. Used dex2jar to extract classes.dex to jar file and decompiled it.

Now when I am in my last step, using APKtool to decode the apk file, however, it shows "-bash: apktool: command not found " eventhough I put all 3 files(aapt, apktool and apktool.jar) into one folder.

How can I decompile with my apktool now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using relative paths to execute apktool, and you are `cd`d to the directory they are in, you have to prefix the command with `./`

So if apktool is at `/path/to/apktool`

And you `cd /path/to`

Then type `./apktool`

Instead of `apktool`

---

If you want to add this folder to your PATH, you can do that too...

Open `~/.bashrc` in a text editor of choice and add this to the bottom of it:

`PATH=$PATH:/path/to`

Where, once again, `/path/to` is the folder that contains `apktool`.

Now you can just type `apktool` from anywhere.

Comment: Working fine just use ./apktool instead of apktool

Comment: What if I want to add the path in system path so that I can run in from terminal without switching directories ???