# "apktool: command not found" error

Tags: android, macos, terminal, apk, apktool

I followed the instructions mentioned here - http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/ for Mac OS to install Apktool 2.X version. I moved the downloaded and renamed files apktool.jar and apktool to /usr/local/bin.

Now when I run apktool from terminal from the same path i.e. "usr/local/bin", I get "apktool: command not found" error.

Referring to one of the posts here on SO about the same issue ([Terminal can't run apktool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656721/terminal-cant-run-apktool)), the suggestion was to run ./apktool instead of apktool and that gives me "-bash: ./apktool: No such file or directory"

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21656902/1961146

Answer (score 14):

The process here is the same as any binary application, with the exception that we additionally have a jar file. The `apktool` file is simply a helper script to prevent you having to type `java -jar apktool.jar` every time. With this in mind, you must have the following.

1. Both files in `/usr/local/bin` or a directory that is in `$PATH` so you can execute it anywhere regardless of path.
2. The helper script (`apktool`) must be executable. `chmod a+x apktool`

If you meet these conditions than running `apktool` anywhere will run the helper script, which runs `apktool.jar`. You can test this by `cd /usr/local/bin`, `java -jar apktool.jar`. Does that work? If so, `apktool.jar` is in the right place.

Answer (score 4):

### installation of apktool

#### For Macbook

```
brew install apktool
```

#### For Linux

```
apt-get install -y apktool
```

#### For Window

you can read installion step for window [DOCS](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/)

Answer (score 0):

check if there is a hidden file extension, like '.txt' behind the script file.